# Measure accuracy of Decision Tree while training

Tags: python, decision-tree, id3

I'm working with a python implementation of a decision tree using a ID3 algorithm, and I would like to know how i could measure accuracy while training the tree in a predefined number of nodes (making it clear: every 10 nodes inserted into the tree makes me measure accuracy so i can build a chart showing accuracy evolution while training) but I'm using a recursive method to do, and I can't use  a node counter and do the measure beacuse the subtree node is passed as argument in the method, and this would make me get accuracy for the subtree. I got kinda out of ideas. 
Thanks for attention!

Here is the code of the method (i tried to translate code, so there may be errors)

```
def decisionTree(Data, Target, Atribute,default):
Root = Node()
index = calc.getindexAttribute(Data,Target)
bigger = ">50K"
smaller = "<=50K"
ibigger = 0
ismaller = 0
a = ""
for i in range (1,len(Data)-1):
    if ibigger > 0 and ismaller > 0:
        break
    elif Data[i][index] == bigger:
        ibigger = ibigger + 1
    elif Data[i][index] == smaller:
        ismaller = ismaller + 1
if ismaller == len(Data) -1 :
    return smaller
elif ibigger == len(Data) -1:
    return bigger
if len(Atribute) == 1:
    return mostCommonValue(Data,Target,Atribute)
else:
    a = BestAttribute(Data,Atribute)
    Root.attribute = a
    Root.mostCommonClass = mostCommonValue(Data,Target, Atribute)
    childs = {}
    Values_A = calc.getAtributeValues(Data,a)
    for y in range (0,len(Valores_A)):
        SubData=[]
        SubData = calc.makeSubData(Data,a,Valores_A[y])
        if len(SubData) == 1:
            return Root
        else:
            childs[Valores_A[y]] = decisionTree(SubData,Target,Delete_matrix(Atribute,a),Root)
            Root.childs = childs
return Root
```